# Using a TimedAspect/@Timed to time methods in third party libraries using micrometer

Tags: java, aspectj, micrometer

I am trying to use micrometer's `@Timed` to time a few methods in a third party external library.

For testing I am using the below Aspect. This works fine and my Pointcut works (see below's log)
However, I am getting a `nullpointer` exception because the `perform` method is looking for the `@Timed` annotation on the method, when this is not available the result is a nullpointer exception.

Question: (By lack of better wording..) Is there a way using a pointcut to add the @Timed information so the perform method will record the metric?

This is the location of the nullpointer exception : https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java#L192

```java
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAspect.class);

    private TimedAspect timedAspect;

    public void setTimedAspect(TimedAspect timedAspect) {
        this.timedAspect = timedAspect;
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com..calledFromPublicMethod(..))")
    public void calledFromPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("calledFromPublicMethod()")
    public Object calledFromPublicMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        log.info("promHistogramWithOutcome_Timed run {}", timedAspect);
        return timedAspect.timedMethod(pjp);
    }
}
```

```
2022-08-23 11:34:52.671  INFO 12580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.example.springboot.aspects.TestAspect  : promHistogramWithOutcome_Timed run io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect@7d3ca5c
2022-08-23 11:34:52.689 ERROR 12580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect.perform(TimedAspect.java:192) ~[micrometer-core-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect.timedMethod(TimedAspect.java:188) ~[micrometer-core-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.example.springboot.aspects.TestAspect.calledFromPublicMethod(TestAspect.java:37) ~[unwoven-classes/:na]
    at com.rvt.test.bare.BareClassExample.calledFromPublicMethod(BareClassExample.java:16) ~[unwoven-classes/:na]
```

Comment: `setTimedAspect` is not getting called and thus `TimedAspect timedAspect` property remains `null` which in turn causes NPE

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko thank you for your time, I have updated the code and added it to the log. `TimedAspect` is set correctly, the log also shows that the exceptions in the method `TimedAspect.perform(..)`

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting an exception that the `@Timed` annotation is missing because the third party library does not use the `@Timed` annotation. :)

You can do a few things:

1. Wrap the third party lib and annotate your wrapper with `@Timed`
2. `timer.record(() -> dontCareAboutReturnValue());` or `timer.recordCallable(() -> returnValue());` see the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers)
3. Instrument manually with Timer.Sample, see the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_storing_start_state_in_timer_sample)